# Tridion Audience Manager - Filtering out subset of audience

Tags: 2013, audience-manager

We have a requirement to filter out a specific subset of our distribution list. Ideally, there would be a way to list out names of companies we wish to exclude. However, it seems there is no way to add multiple company names to the "is not" selector. We have tried many different delimiters (, ; : " ' AND OR etc.).

[image]

If that is not possible, another approach could be to use a new Custom Contact extended details field, as per the documentation here:
https://docs.rws.com/792475/101061/sdl-tridion-2013-sp1/custom-contact-extended-details

The distribution list is imported from an external data source, but I still think this approach could work, since it explicitly calls out this scenario, if I'm reading it correctly. We'd like to  gain some confidence before attempting this approach, as syncing issues can be difficult to correct.